# Check if a value belongs to a hash

Tags: algorithm

I'm not sure if this is actually possible thus I ask here. Does anyone knows of an algorithm that would allow something like this?

```
const values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const hash = createHash(values); // => xjaks14sdffdghj23h4kjhgd9f81nkjrsdfg9aiojd
hash.includes('b'); // => true
hash.includes('v'); // => false
```

What this snippet does, is it first creates some sort of `hash` from a list of values, then checks if the certain value belongs to that hash.

Comment: What is your hash? Is this a reference to some particular language?

Comment: That is totally up to the specific hashing algorithm used. For some this is possible, for most probably not. You will need to specify this more. If you talk about cryptographic hash functions the answer is no since it would violate one of the rules. Informal: *"a small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value"* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)).

Comment: Let's prove or disprove before down vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hash functions in general

The primary idea of hash functions is to **reduce the space**, that is the functions are **not injective** as they map from a bigger domain to a smaller.

[image]

So they produce **collisions**. That is, there are different elements `x` and `y` that get mapped to the same hash value:

```
h(x) = h(y)
```

So basically you loose information of the given argument `x`.

However, in order to answer the question whether all values are contained you would need to **keep all** information (or at least all non-duplicates). This is obviously not possible for nearly all practical hash-functions.

Possible hash-functions would be **identity** function:

```
h(x) = x for all x
```

but this doesn't reduce the space, not practical.

A natural idea would be to compute hash values of the individual elements and then concatenate them, like

```
h(a, b, c) = (h(a), h(b), h(c))
```

But this again doesn't reduce the space, hash values are as long as the message, not practical.

Another possibility is to **drop all duplicates**, so given values `[a, b, c, a, b]` we only keep `[a, b, c]`. But this, in most examples, only reduces the space marginally, again not practical.

But no matter what you do, you can not reduce more than the amount of **non-duplicates**. Else you wouldn't be able to answer the question for some values. For example if we use `[a, b, c, a]` but only keep `[a, b]`, we are unable to answer *"was `c` contained"* correctly.

---

### Perfect hash functions

However, there is the field of **perfect** hash functions ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)). Those are hash-functions that are **injective**, they don't produce collisions.

In some areas they are of interest.

For those you may be able to answer that question, for example if computing the inverse is **easy**.

---

### Cryptographic hash functions

If you talk about **cryptographic hash functions**, the answer is **no**.

Those need to have three properties ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)):

- Pre-image resistance - Given `h` it should be difficult to find `m : hash(m) = h`
- Second pre-image resistance - Given `m` it should be difficult to find `m' : hash(m) = hash(m')`
- Collision resistance - It should be difficult to find `(m, m') : hash(m) = hash(m')`

Informally you have especially:

> A small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value.

If you now would have such a hash value you would be able to easily reconstruct it by asking whether some values are contained. Using that you can easily construct collisions on purpose and stuff like that.

Details would however depend on the specific hash algorithm.

For a toy-example let's use the previous algorithm that simply removes all duplicates:

```
[a, b, c, a, a] -> [a, b, c]
```

In that case we find messages like

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c, a]
[a, a, b, b, c]
...
```

that all map to the same hash value.

Comment: +1 Practically speaking, no, but in theory, yes, any perfect hash function has an inverse that could be derived and used to check for inclusion.

Comment: This is really detailed answer. Thank you very much @Zabuza for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If the hash function produces collisions (as almost all hash function do) this cannot be possible. 
Think about it this way if for example `h('abc') = x` and `h('abd') = x`, how can you decide based on `x` if the original string contains `'d'`?

You could arguably decide to use identity as a has function, which would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial solution will be a simple hash concatenation.

```
func createHash(values) {
  var hash;
  foreach (v in values)
     hash += MD5(v);
  return hash;
}
```

Can it be done with fixed length hash and variable input? I'd bet it's impossible.

In case of string hash (such as used in HashMaps), because it is additive, I think we can match partially (prefix match but not suffix).

```
const values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const hash = createStringHash(values); // => xjaks14sdffdghj23h4kjhgd9f81nkjrsdfg9aiojd
hash.includes('a'); // => true
hash.includes('a', 'b'); // => true
hash.includes('a', 'b', 'v'); // => false
```

Comment: I like the prefix/suffix example, adds something new to all other answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Bit arrays

If you don't care what the resulting hash looks like, I'd recommend just using a bit array.

- Take the range of all possible values
- Map this to the range of integers starting from 0
- Let each bit in our hash indicate whether or not this value appears in the input

This will require 1 bit for every possible value (which could be a lot of bits for large  ranges).

Note: **this representation is optimal** in terms of the number of bits used, assuming there's no limit on the number of elements you can have (beyond 1 of each possible value) - if it were possible to use any fewer bits, you'd have an algorithm that's capable of providing guaranteed compression of any data, which is impossible by [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

#### For example:

If your range is a-z, you can map this to 0-25, then [a,d,g,h] would map to:

```
 10010011000000000000000000 = 38535168 = 0x24c0000
(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
```

### More random-looking hashes

If you care what the hash looks like, you could take the output from the above and perform a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) on it to map it either to the same length hash or a longer hash.

One trivial example of such a map would be to increment the resulting hash by a randomly chosen but deterministic value (i.e. it's the same for every hash we convert) - you can also do this for each byte (with wrap-around) if you want (e.g. byte0 = (byte0+5)%255, byte1 = (byte1+18)%255).

To determine whether an element appears, the simplest approach would be to reverse the above operation (subtract instead of add) and then just check if the corresponding bit is set. Depending on what you did, it might also be possible to only convert a single byte.

### Bloom filters

If you don't mind false positives, I might recommend just using a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) instead.

In short, this sets multiple bits for each value, and then checks each of those bits to check whether a value is in our collection. But the bits that are set for one value can overlap with the bits for other values, which allows us to significantly reduce the number of bits required at the cost of a few false positives (assuming the total number of elements isn't too large).